# How do I return only rows with non duplicate ids AND a matching value on another column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table where I need to check if multiple `ids` exist with different `types` and return the `ids` that have *only one* record and has `trial` in the `type` column.

For example using this table:

```
id|type
--------
12|trial
12|purchase
13|trial
14|purchase
14|trial
15|trial
```

I want to return the following results:

```
id|type
--------
13|trial
15|trial
```

Since these only have one record containing a trial.  If an `id` contains a trial and a purchase I want those rows to be excluded.

Comment: Unrelated, but: Postgres 9.1 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade to the current version as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Its can be done by using inner query

```
select * from t where id IN (select id from t group by id having count(*) <= 1) AND trial = 'trial';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want not exists:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.type = 'trial' and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.type <> 'trial');
```

If you just want `id`s that meet this condition, I would suggests aggregation:

```
select t.*
from t
group by t.id
having sum( (t.type <> 'trial')::int ) = 0;
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of these but they don't seem to be working, the second one there is no t2 or column named trial

Comment: @staten12 . . . The column name `trial` came from your second table in the question.  I've fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

One more alternative, using a `JOIN`. The sub-query limits the results to `id` values that are unique, then the `WHERE` clause further filters that down to the `type` value you're interested in.

```
select 
  t.id,
  t.type
from
  @table as t
JOIN
  (
    select
      id
    from @table
    group by id
    having count(*)=1
  ) as d
    on d.id = t.id
where type = 'trial';
```

Returns the result set you have in the question.